# Display string spacing correctly in Jupyter-notebook dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

A Dataframe

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
'COL1':["string", "string string"],
'COL2':["string  string", "string    string"]
})
```

When it displays in JupyterLab

[image: Notice the space doesn't show right]

Notice the number of space characters inside the strings is not the same as the dataframe.
How can I prevent this behaviour?

Python 3.6.5

Comment: When browser display HTML then it treats many space as one space. is this changing calculation on this dataframe ?  If not then why bother this.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing data cleaning and checking typos, bad entries, etc. It got confusing for a moment.